# Menu from database in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to echo Menu from database..

Here's my code..

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\Menu;
use app\models\Names;

$names_model    = new Names();
$product_names  = $names_model->findNames();

foreach ($product_names as $product_name => $val) {
    $name = $val['name'];
}
echo Menu::widget([
    'items' => [
    // Important: you need to specify url as 'controller/action',
    // not just as 'controller' even if default action is used.
        ['label' => $name, 'url' => ['site/index']],
    ],
    ]);
?>
```

Now, I want somehow to use this foreach loop inside Menu widget.. Or is there any other solution to my problem?
This function findNames is correct inside my Names model.

Comment: Is the url the same for all names?

Comment: @Barry No, the url is different, but I'll just use column value from db like this $val['url']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also build up the items array outside the menu widget like this

```
$items = [];
foreach ($product_names as $product_name => $val) {
    $items[] = ['name' => $val['name'], 'url' => $val['url']];
}

echo Menu::widget([
    'items' => $items,
]);
```

Comment: I tried the way you said and it gives me this error:
syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']'

Comment: @MarkoMikulić Sorry, missed a closing bracket, see modifid answer.